# How does one determine how many landing gears are needed for my ship?

Tags: starfield

I'm trying to build up a ship that has plenty of storage using the best available parts for myself. I have rank 2 starship design and rank 4 piloting which basically means I can build/pilot Class C starships and have access to some good parts.

To try to see what my limits are, I'm starting to build out lots of cargo, then trim it down til it just just enough. However I'm not sure how to determine what the landing gear is needed. Have the "minimum gear count" error and can't clear it. I already have 9 gears on my ship. And I only have access to the 220CB and NG-10 landing gears at this starport.

[image]

How does the game determine how many are needed? I'm assuming it's a function of the mass, engine power, and the footprint of the ship.

---

I ended up removing some of the bulkier storage tanks and I was able to get away with seven gears total with 1979 mass. Six each with one lander thrust and one with four. That's 10 lander thrust total for my 1979 mass.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning message is unfortunately vaguely named. It doesn't actually count the number of landing gear on your ship. It counts the amount of "Lander Thrust" your ship has in total.

Lander Thrust is a property on the Landing Gear itself, for instance:
[image]

As the Hope 55 showcases, Landing Thrust need not be 1 to 1 with actual Landing Gear parts.

The amount of Lander Thrust needed is simple -- ship mass divided by 200. (Though because Lander Thrust is not available in fractional form, this invariably means rounding up). 1970 mass means you need 10 landing thrust, which you got from a mere 7 actual landing gear pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The 220CBs had only 1 lander thrust each while the NG-20 in the front had 4. Giving a total of 10 lander thrust.

Comment: Is this mentioned anywhere in the game? Or did people just figured this out on their own?

Comment: I haven't seen it anywhere in game, but I found out about it after seeing the statistic and googling "what the heck is lander thrust"?

Comment: Where are you getting 1970 mass from? OP's picture shows significantly more mass than that.

Comment: @TylerH I commented on what the final configuration was (that worked) on the other answer and I ended up with 1970.

Comment: Game documentation is... terribad

Answer (score 0):

It is every 200 mass = 1 landing gear, and you have 2704 mass, so you would need 13.52 landing gears. Rounding up, you need 14 landing gears.

Comment: In my final configuration, I ended up with 8 gears total (including the landing bay) at 1970 mass and I couldn't remove any. This seems way off, I think there's a lot more to it than that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJrea.jpg